# Vb. how to make the file save files in a folder iam using the files in form

Tags: vb.net

Lets Says I Want To Make A Think Like Saver Forum But Another Think Like
Folder Browser Diadlog Download / Save Files I Use In The Forum Not Load Then Save
Files I Use It And In The Folder They Select (Another Pc) I Want It To Save The Files/Download In The Folder And They Will Be Think Named Wolfteam.exe Thats Mean Start The  Game And Use The Files In The Game Folder
Thanks For Help.

Comment: What? I think you might want to work on re-wording this to make your question clearer. And don't have each word start with a capital letter.

Comment: A Little Punctuation Would Be Nice Too...and try to describe the problem for the many many people who never heard of Think Like Saver Forum

Comment: It looks like you could use your own folder in the `ApplicationData` directory as the place to store the files. Please see [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) for how to use it. Also, perhaps you would like to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) to help with writing your question in English.